# MySQlL Удаление нескольких таблиц одним запросом

Tags: mysql

Друзья, просветите, пожалуйста.
Если мне нужно дропнуть несколько таблиц из базы одним запросом, то как это сделать?
`Drop Table If EXISTS` удаляет одну таблицу или несколько через запятую.
Есть ли возможность как-то соединить `Drop` и `Select`, если `Select` выбирает наименования таблицы?

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1, table2;
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это-то я знаю, конечно, в вопросе и написал "Drop Table If EXISTS удаляет одну таблицу или несколько через запятую.". Имелось в виду, можно ли из результата запроса Select удалить таблицы по наименованию.

Comment: @Василий, извиняюсь, невнимательно прочитала вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Точно также можно удалить несколько таблиц. Просто перечислите их через запятую. Например:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1, table2;
```

Источник: официальная документация MySQL http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/DROP_TABLE.html

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли возможность как-то соединить Drop и Select, если Select выбирает наименования таблицы?

Что-то типа

```
SET @strSQL:=(SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ',GROUP_CONCAT(TABLE_NAME),';')
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
              WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MyDatabase' 
                AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Prefix%');
PREPARE stmt FROM @strSQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
SET @strSQL = NULL;
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, нечто подобное и необходимо.